# Browser not remembering session when user returns?

Tags: session, cakephp, cookies, session-cookies

I run a site built on CakePHP. A week or so ago, the site started half-forgetting that I'm logged in if I leave the page. So, suppose I do the following:

1. Log in
2. Navigate to some page on the site
3. Enter "google.com" in the URL bar and wait for that to load
4. Enter my site in the URL bar and wait for that to load

My expected behaviour is that I return to the page I had navigated to. Instead, in Chrome only, I'm now forwarded to the login page, but can enter anything at all as a username and password and will be sent to the page I'd navigated to after that (logged in). I get the expected behaviour in Safari and Firefox.

The problem happens only on the production site (https://example.com), but not on the local development site through MAMP (http://example.local:8888).

I'd love to do more debugging, but I'm afraid my knowledge of how the expected behaviour is achieved is thin enough that I'm at a bit of a loss, except to say that clearing cookies hasn't helped. Any suggestions on what I should look into?

Comment: Found something, I think. Looks like Chrome is going to port 80 when "example.com" is typed into the URL bar, while Safari and Firefox are going to port 443. If I type "https://example.com" into the URL bar instead in Chrome, I'm forwarded as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to your original post, but we need to know a few things to further help you:

What version of CakePHP are you running?

Things to check are:
The /app/Config/core.php file's Session configurations.  What is it configured to do for storing Session data?  According to CakePHP's Session documentation:

- php - Saves sessions with the standard settings in your php.ini file.
- cake - Saves sessions as files inside tmp/sessions. This is a good option when on hosts that don’t allow you to write outside your own home dir.
- database - Use the built-in database sessions.
- cache - Use the built-in cache sessions.

Whichever option you have set, make sure you have the privileges to do so e.g. you're using "cake" sessions and need to have write access to the tmp/sessions folder on your production server.

If the Session configurations aren't the issue, I suggest going to your AppController.php and in the beforeFilter() function, debugging the session data:

CakePHP 1.x and 2.x:

```
debug($this->Session->read());
```

CakePHP 3.x:

```
$session = $this->request->session();
debug($session->read());
```

This will output at the top of the screen what's store inside your Session.  I hope that helps you resolve your issue.

Comment: Using version 2.2.3. While it seems odd to me that the configuration in core.php would be the problem (since the sessions are fine on Safari and Firefox but not Chrome), the problems may have started when I rebuilt the server from an AWS image, and in my experience those can mess with permissions. "default" in core.php is set to php, and according to phpinfo() session.save_path is /var/lib/php/5.6/session. Permissions are drwxrwx--- with owner root:apache. Thoughts?

Comment: Tried logging $this->Session->read(), and the output for the page immediately before I leave the site and immediately after I return (the latter renders as a login page) are the same with the exception of the time and an additional element in [_Token][carftokens], as I guess is expected. In particular, when CAKE renders the login page on return, it knows who the logged in user is.

Comment: Found a hint as to what's going on, I think. Added a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf the question author in order to move it to the answer space)*.

Forwarding in vhosts file was to the http version of the site, and I was leaning on CakePHP's Security component to redirect to https. Problem arose because when the default http://example.com/index.php (for example) is redirected to https://example.com/index.php by the Security component, CakePHP stops there, and doesn't check whether the user's session should be showing a different page.

Resolution was to edit vhosts to redirect to https (as I should have to begin with). One snag worth noting: it's important to make sure that the virtual host defined in vhosts.conf doesn't conflict with any in ssl.conf -- otherwise the Security component gives a redirect loop. My ssl virtual host is now defined entirely in ssl.conf.